# How to prevent imageview jumping at recyclerview item?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have such xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/message_list_item_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_job_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

    <com.lsjwzh.widget.materialloadingprogressbar.CircleProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loader"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:mlpb_arrow_height="2dp"
        app:mlpb_arrow_width="7dp"
        app:mlpb_enable_circle_background="true"
        app:mlpb_progress_stoke_width="2.5dp"
        app:mlpb_show_arrow="false" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_company"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_to_notepad"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_to_notepad"
            android:layout_gravity="end"/>


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and my imageviews which are contained by items of list can't stay at the same place. It looks like this:

[image]

maybe I have some problems with adapter, and if I have some problems with adapter I will add its code. I tried to use `RelativeLayout` with it tags and as I see weights at `LinearLayout` don't help with this problem. So, how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the reason why it's happening. The problem is here:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_company"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_to_notepad"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_to_notepad"
            android:layout_gravity="end"/>


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

You have set the TextView width as 0dp and there is no weight given to any elements. This means that the ImageView is actually dependent on your TextView and therefore changes as the content inside it changes. 
Hopefully, replacing this with the following code might help you.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_company"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_to_notepad"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/add_to_notepad" />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Suggestion: I see a lot of nesting in your code, try using a Constraint Layout or Relative Layout to make a more simple XML. Good luck.